# Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError with installing bundler gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hell All,

Since last few days I am facing a wierd issue with installing some gems. I have tried installing bundler gem

```
Fetching: bundler-1.1.3.gem ( 18%)ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/gems/bundler-1.1.3.gem)
```

I have checked my internet connection and it is working fine with other downloads.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the rubygems site getting thrashed. Try downloading the gem file directly with `wget` or `curl` and then install directly from the gem file, e.g.:

```
$ gem install <path_to_gem_file.gem>
```